# How to create a custom validator in ASP.NET Core that fires for invalid input too?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding, asp.net-core-3.1, customvalidator, model-validation

I have created a custom validator for a `DateTime` field in ASP.NET Core 3.1 as  shown below:

```cs
[CustomDate]
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

public class CustomDate : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //… some logic
    }
}
```

However, my problem is that this custom validator fires only when I put a date value in the text box control. It does not fire for invalid inputs like e.g. when I put a string 'aaa' in the text box.

My question is how to make this custom validator fire even for invalid inputs like 'string', etc.

The reason is I want to make this custom validator replace `[Required]`, `[ReqularExpression]`, etc. A sort of 'One ring (validator) to rule them all'. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a `IModelValidator` here, as opposed to a `ValidationAttribute`? The latter tend to be a bit more straightforward, and _should_ still satisfy your requirements.

Comment: @JeremyCaney because I don't want to apply lots of validation attribute on the field like required, reqularexpression, etc. I want all my work to be done by my custom attribute itself. Also I want to ask how to capture invalid inputs for the field eg when I enter string value on the field then how to capture this.

Comment: Well, I meant a custom `ValidationAttribute`, which would allow you to customize the logic. As far as your `IModelValidator` is concerned, I’d need to verify a few points before answering. But I _thought_ that the `Model` property would return a nullable instance of whatever the model type was—so `DateTime?` in this case. If so, the value `some` wouldn’t get bound, and the `Model` will return `null`. I’m not sure what the behavior of `Convert.DateTime()` would be for a `null` value, but I’d have _thought_ it would throw an `InvalidFormatException`, or possibly default to `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: Even if I use derive my custom class with ValidationAttribute then also the custom validator does not fire for invalid inputs.

Comment: I’ve provided a (lengthy) explanation of what’s happening below, and why it might not be a concern. In addition, however, I wanted to highlight an un(der)documented feature which allows you to [create composite validators](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7965#issuecomment-406755480) using the [`ValidationProviderAttribute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.dataannotations.validationproviderattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1). This doesn’t answer your immediate question, but it does address your objective of grouping multiple `ValidationAttribute`s together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** When you submit a value that can't be converted to `DateTime`, model binding fails. Since there is already a validation error associated with the property, subsequent validation—including your `CustomDate` validator—doesn't fire. Your property is still getting validated, however: If you enter a value of `aaa`, `ModelState.IsValid` will return `false`.

---

The code you had originally posted *should* be working fine—but I suspect it's not working the way you're *expecting* it to. Most notably, your confusion likely stems from the following statement:

> "…this custom validator fires only when I put a date value in the text box control."

That is *also* true! Let me walk through the process.

### Original Code

To help illustrate this, I hope you don't mind me resurrecting your original code sample, as it's useful to have concrete reference to work off of.

```cs
[CustomDate]
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

public class CustomDate : Attribute, IModelValidator
{
    public IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(ModelValidationContext context)
    {
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(context.Model) > DateTime.Now)
            return new List<ModelValidationResult> {
                new ModelValidationResult("", "Invalid - future date")
            };
        else if (Convert.ToDateTime(context.Model) < new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))
            return new List<ModelValidationResult> {
                new ModelValidationResult("", "Invalid - date is less than 1970 year")
            };
        else
            return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidationResult>();
    }
}
```

### Validation Process

Before I walk through the process, there are four underlying considerations that are important to be aware of here:

1. Model **binding** occurs *before* model **validation**.
2. Model binding will raise its own validation errors if binding fails.
3. Validation attributes are only evaluated on properties that remain `IsValid`.
4. The `ModelValidationContext.Model` property is typed to the validated property—so, in this case, a `DateTime` value.

#### Use Case #1: Invalid Value

Given these considerations, here's what's happening when you submit a value of e.g. `aaa` in the field mapped to your validated `DOB` property:

1. The model binder attempts to bind a value of `aaa` to a `DateTime` property.
2. The model binder fails, adding a `ModelError` to your `ModelStateDictionary`.
3. Your `CustomDate` validator never fires because *the field has already failed validation*.

#### Use Case #2: Missing Value

It's instructive to look at another test case. Instead of putting in `aaa`, just don't put a value in at all. In this case, the process looks a bit different:

1. The model binder doesn't find a value for your `DateTime` property, so no binding occurs.
2. Your model's property initializes to `DateTime`'s default value of `0001-01-01 00:00:00`.
3. Your `CustomDate` validator fires, adding a `ModelError` because "Invalid - date is less than 1970 year".

### Analysis

As you can see above, it is *true* that your `CustomDate` validator isn't firing when a bogus date is submitted. But that *doesn't* mean that validation isn't occurring. Instead, validation has *already* happened *and* failed. If you enter a valid date—or don't enter a date at all—then a model binding error won't occur, and your `CustomDate` validator will be executed as expected.

#### Revisiting Your Question

> "How to make this custom validator to fire even for invalid inputs like 'string' etc."

Ultimately, I haven't answered that question. But I *think* my answer will explain *why* that's happening, and why your input is *still* getting validated despite that. Keep in mind that even if your `CustomDate` validator *did* fire, it would act the same as if you hadn't submitted a value at all, since the `context.Model` value would have defaulted to `0001-01-01 00:00:00`. The main difference is that you're not getting the same error message, since the error is coming from a different source.

#### Forcing Validation

I don't recommend this, but if you *really* wanted your `CustomDate` validator to fire, you could apply it to a `string` property instead. In that case, model binding wouldn't fail and your `CustomDate` validator would still get called. If you pursue this, you'll need to put in additional validation to ensure that the date is in the correct format (e.g., by preempting or handling `InvalidFormatException`s). But, of course, your date would be stored as a `string`, which likely isn't what you want.

#### Code Suggestions

This is a bit outside the scope of your original question, but while I'm here I'd recommend the following:

1. You won't need to do a `Convert.ToDateTime()` in your validator; your `context.Model` field is *already* a `DateTime`. You just need to cast it back to a `DateTime` object (e.g., `(DateTime)context.Model`) so your code knows that.
2. At minimum, you should consider using `<input type="date" />` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)) which, on most browsers, will restrict input to a correct date while also providing a basic date picker.
3. Alternatively, there are a number of more sophisticated date/time controls written in JavaScript that you might consider implementing if you require more control over the presentation and client-side validation.